# gwt redraw with timer

Tags: multithreading, gwt, extjs, rpc

I'm new to GWT and I have a big problem.
I have a gwt/extjs gwt2.2.0 app. I need to build a chart which will show the real-time information about the quantity of incoming messages every second. Something like system monitor.
The only way I've found is to add the code which calls for messageQueueSize from server and adds it to the area chart to timer block with timer.shedule(1000) and all of this to

```
$while(true)
```

block. When I'm trying to run my application my app is looping(because While occupy all the thread). please help me to resolve this problem or to find the idea for realizing this part of the app.
here is the code of what I'm trying to do:

```
$ public class ExampleChart extends ContentPanel{

    ArrayList<String> timeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Long> queueSize = new ArrayList<Long>();
    private final ServerManagementAsync serverManagementSvc = GWT.create(ServerManagement.class);
      public ContentPanel createChart(final String customerId, boolean warrant){
       setHeading("Messages by domain");
       setFrame(true);
       setSize(550, 400);
       setLayout(new FitLayout());

       String url = "/gxt/chart/open-flash-chart.swf";
       final Chart chart = new Chart(url);

       chart.setBorders(true);

       timeList = getTimeList(timeList);
       while (warrant){
           Timer t = new Timer(){
               public void run(){
                   ExampleChart ec = new ExampleChart();
                   AsyncCallback<Long> ac = new AsyncCallback<Long>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onSuccess(Long integer) {
                           timeList = getTimeList(timeList);
                           if (queueSize.size()<11){
                               queueSize.add(integer);
                           } else{
                               for (int i = 0; i<queueSize.size()-1; i++){
                                   queueSize.set(i,queueSize.get(i+1));
                               }
                           }
                           chart.setChartModel(getAreaChart(timeList, queueSize));
                           add(chart);
                           repaint();
                       }
                   };
                   serverManagementSvc.getMessageQueueSize(customerId, ac);
               }
           };
           t.schedule(2000);
       }
       chart.setChartModel(getAreaChart(timeList, queueSize));
       add(chart);
       repaint();
       return this;

    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTimeList(ArrayList<String> TimeList){
        ArrayList<String> timeList = TimeList;
        if (timeList.size() < 11){
            timeList.add(getCurrentTime());
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i<timeList.size()-1; i++){
                timeList.set(i, timeList.get(i+1));
            }
            timeList.set(10, getCurrentTime());
        }
        return timeList;
    }

    public String getCurrentTime(){
        Date date = new Date();
        String hrs = Integer.toString(date.getHours());
        String min = Integer.toString(date.getMinutes());
        String sec = Integer.toString(date.getSeconds());
        return hrs + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
    }
    public ChartModel getAreaChart(ArrayList<String> dateList, ArrayList<Long> queueSize)
    {
        ChartModel cm = new ChartModel("Messages per domain", "font-size: 14px; font-family: Verdana;");
        cm.setBackgroundColour("#ffffff");
        XAxis xa = new XAxis();
        xa.setLabels(dateList);
        cm.setXAxis(xa);
        AreaChart area1 = new AreaChart();
        area1.setFillAlpha(0.3f);
        area1.setColour("#ff0000");
        area1.setFillColour("#ff0000");
        for (int n = 0; n<queueSize.size(); n++){
                area1.addValues(queueSize.get(n));
        }
        cm.addChartConfig(area1);

        return cm;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, but I've found another solution. I can create timer and instead of t.shedule(2000) I use t.scheduleRepeating(2000). so i don't need if() or while(). thank you anyway. If needed, write me, I'll post the working code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **'if(warrant)'** statement instead of **'while(warrant)'**. **'While'** statement is not required here since timer repeatedly executes run() method for every 2000 ms.

You should not fire async calls without knowing previous one has returned or not.

Replace your while block with the following code block.

```
       boolean isAsyncCallReturned = true;
       if (warrant)
       {
             Timer t = new Timer()
             {
                public void run()
                {
                   if( isAsyncCallReturned )
                   {  
                      ExampleChart ec = new ExampleChart();
                      AsyncCallback<Long> ac = new AsyncCallback<Long>() 
                      {
                             @Override
                             public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) 
                             {
                             }

                             @Override
                             public void onSuccess(Long integer) 
                             {
                                    timeList = getTimeList(timeList);
                                    if (queueSize.size()<11)
                                    {
                                         queueSize.add(integer);
                                    } 
                                    else
                                    {
                                           for (int i = 0; i<queueSize.size()-1; i++)
                                           {
                                                 queueSize.set(i,queueSize.get(i+1));
                                           }
                                    }
                                    chart.setChartModel(getAreaChart(timeList, queueSize));
                                    add(chart);
                                    repaint();
                                    isAsyncCallReturned = true;
                             }
                    };
                    isAsyncCallReturned = false;
                    serverManagementSvc.getMessageQueueSize(customerId, ac);
                  }
                }
            };
            t.schedule(2000);
       }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I've found another solution. I can create timer adn instead of t.shedule(2000) I use t.scheduleRepeating(2000). so i don't  need if() or while(). thank you anyway. If needed, write me, I'll post the working code.